# Sorting tables by columns jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wouldn't want to use plugin to sort my table such as tablesorter because it would be an overhead for desired functionality.

I want to sort my table only once when page is loaded I don't want that functionality to be available all the time.

So imagine if I have i rows each containing k columns and k #2 is the one I want to use for this sorting so my sorting would be based on this column in descending order I want to sort their rows.

Something like this :

```
        var $rows = $("#score-table tr");
            $.each($rows, function(index, row) {
                //sort table
            });
```

Comment: This one is verylightweight : http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/

Comment: what do you want to sort it by? class name, id, text value, etc...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well if you know which column you are sorting on you can easily sort the table using javascript's [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
var $tbody = $('table tbody');
$tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a,b){ 
    var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(1)').text(); // can replace 1 with the column you want to sort on
    var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(1)').text(); // this will sort on the second column
            // if a < b return 1
    return tda < tdb ? 1 
           // else if a > b return -1
           : tda > tdb ? -1 
           // else they are equal - return 0    
           : 0;           
}).appendTo($tbody);
```

If you want ascending you just have to reverse the `>` and `<`

If they are just numbers you can just do `a-b` for ascending or `b-a` for descending

After the sort is complete just append it back to the body and your done

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/APJtU/)